# Remove hyperlink behaviour from child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an anchor tag inside which I append some divs through jQuery. I want that the 'hyperlink' effect of the parent `<a>` tag should not appear in the appended child elements.

How can we achieve this with jQuery or in some other way.

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H8x8z/)** of what I want.

**UPDATE:**
Most of the answers tell how to remove the click effect. Isn't there something that can prevent every default behavior of anchor tag from child elements?

Comment: What do you mean by "hyperlink effect"? The underline? The "click to navigate" functionality?

Comment: Can you post the code you are referring to or a fiddle?

Comment: I assume he means the directing to a new URL. Please can you post your code Arvind?

Comment: @JasonP I mean the default beahvior of hyperlink like underlines/clicks and everything else.

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good idea to reevaluate why you are using an anchor tag to begin with.

Comment: Provide the markup you are working with.

Comment: Please see the simplified fiddle more clarity.

Comment: As you can see from some answers, that is possible, but involves "undoing" a lot of default stuff. I agree with @JasonP, are you sure you want your div inside the anchor? Why not just add it after the anchor?

Comment: @JasonP Adding anckor tag is a constraint.

Comment: This would be ideal: http://jsfiddle.net/sQNbG/

Comment: @JasonP I have a very complex situation. The child elements have to be in the anchor tag. it is the requirement.

Comment: What specific anchor behaviours you need to prevent/change (apart from underline and following link)?

Comment: @matewka all default behaviors of anchor tag.

Comment: As far as I know, the one and only anchor behaviour is that it follows the link from `href` attribute. Do you also want to change its look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pLGNh/)

Ok. Here is some sample HTML

```
<a href="google.com" id="first">
    <div>
        <p>Blah</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Blah</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Blah</p>
    </div>
</a>

<a href="google.com" id="second">
    <div>
        <p>Blah 2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Blah 2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Blah 2</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

This CSS will remove the underscore, change the font color and the cursor

```
div{
    display: inline;
}

#second{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    cursor: default;
}
```

The jquery removes the click event from the children

```
$('#second').children().each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

**Update**: Further to your comments, what you are trying to do is complicated and kind of weird. You say for some reason you **have to** wrap the divs in an achor tag but not have them inherit the properties. You will have to make some trade-off. The trick is to **remove the 'href'** from the a tag. You would not have to write any jQuery/javascript for this. As a matter of fact you don't even need any CSS then. Essentially, remove all the css and jquery from the above and remove the href from the second a.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pLGNh/3/)**

Comment: It is close to what I want. But I cant select the children like normal text. These still have some behavior of anchor tag.

Comment: You won't be able to select text like that. You could write a jquery function but it won't behave the same way as normally selecting a text. What exactly are you trying to achieve? I am sure there is a better way to do all this.

Comment: I just want that the appended elements in the anchor tag should not behave like anchor tag.

Comment: The update seems to work. Simple enough, solves the problem I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :first-child Selector. Look at http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Comment: What good it will do? Please back your answer with full evidence.

Comment: It should get your first children div of your a tag. Am I wrong?

Comment: I dont want first div. I want all children and remove anchor effedct from them.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove underline with CSS:

```
a div {
    text-decoration: none
}
```

To stop anchor from following its `href` attribute you need to bind a handler to `click` event which returns false. In jQuery you can achieve it this way:

```
$('a div').on('click', function() {
    // do whatever you want to do here

    return false;
});
```

I edited selectors (added `div`) after you provided jsfiddle. Still, there is one more thing. According to your fiddle I assume you didn't want "Something" to be wrapped with div.
It should look like this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H8x8z/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You should add an eventlistener to your anchors and [prevent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) the default behaviour:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if(e.target.tagName=="DIV") e.preventDefault();
});
```